# NVidia graphics card not detected anymore after BIOS update

Tags: bios, windows-11, kubuntu, display-driver, nvidia

I currently have a problem after installing a BIOS update for my laptop. It runs an NVIDIA GeForce 3080 Ti. I am on a dual boot system with Windows 11 and Kubuntu 23.04 (Kernel 6.2). The problems only affect the Kubuntu installation. Everything works perfectly fine in Windows 11.

After the BIOS update this is my current situation

- NVIDIA Control Panel does not show the graphics card anymore
- `lscpi` shows the graphics card
- I did not find anything suspicious
- reinstalling `nvidia-drivers` as well as `nvidia-dkms` did not help and the behavioud stays the same
- `lsmod | grep nvidia` gives me (I am not really sure if there should be more output here):

```
nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight    16384  0
video                      69632  2 nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,i915
wmi                        40960  4 video,nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight,wmi_bmof,dell_wmi_descriptor
```

- `nvidia-smi` tells me it cannot communicate to the graphics card

Would be great if anybody has an idea what I can do. If you need additional information or logs I'll gladly update the question

Comment: With Windows 11 you have to have Secure Boot enabled and if you updated UEFI (BIOS is no longer used in consumer grade products since ~2012) then you must sign the Nvidia drivers again.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I remember having to sign the drivers when I installed them back then but no prompt came up when i purge nvidia-* now and reinstall. Is there a way to force this again? Sorry for using the term BIOS meant UEFI of course but the term just wont leave my head ;)

Comment: You have to run mokutil

Comment: thanks. checked modinfo but that gives me no sign of the drivers not being signed correctly. however modprobe nvidia does give me
"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service". This points to your theory right?

Comment: @relief.melone - Yes; That would prove their theory.

Comment: unfortunately accepting my own answer has to wait. while enrolling the way i described in the answer did bring back the graphics card to x server settings and nvidia-smi, there still is no card present in the systems monitor, nor do any games run or xrandr is able to pick up again my second monitor. Did I miss something? i did prime-select nvidia but that also did not have any effect

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Thanks for the help in the comments. It was correct that I needed to resign the drivers. After that everything is back to normal. For everybody struggeling with this here are the steps I took.

1. Generate a private key and certificate

```sh
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -subj "/CN=My Key/"
```

2. Import the machine owner key. when prompted enter a password that you will be asked for after rebooting the system

```sh
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

3. reboot the system. Enroll the MOK and enter the password previously created
4. sign the nvidia drivers. Navigate back to the folder with your private key and certificate and enter

```sh
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n nvidia)
```

5. reboot again and the graphics card should be detected again